# How to freeze columns in SSIS packages in order to have exactly same columns in both source and destination

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl

I'm creating an SSIS package to load .XLSX file in a SQL Server staging table. I need to control the columns number in my Excel source file in order to have exactly the same columns in both source and destination. The issue is that even when I add manually more columns in my Excel source file the data flow task succeeds which is not what I need because it's a technical constraint to me. It should fail, because I need to redirect failure and rename the file.

Comment: Not sure what you mean here. I seem to be reading that you're suggesting you have an xlsx file, which is a source in your data flow and has the definitions of the data in your file. you then are adding more columns to that file and the data flow isn't failing? I'm *guessing* that you're using a SQL command to get the data (like `SELECT {columns} FROM [Sheet1$A1:Y]`); if so, then no the dataflow won't fail because the definition of those columns hasn't changed if you're adding columns at the right most position (`Z` in the example above). If you use `Table View or Name` you would see a failure.

Comment: @Larnu Thank you for your answer, I'm using Table name variable in data access mode and I need that the data flow task goes to failure if there are more columns (or less) in my source file, to rename the file and show that it contains an error.

Comment: If you're using a variable name to simply state the sheet name, then the dataflow **will** fail if the definition of the file changes; especially if they are removed. I'm therefore not sure what your question is here.

Comment: @Larnu I'm using a variable to get the sheet name dynamically by a script task and it works fine, but the issue is that the data flow task doesn't fail when I add more columns to the source file, than what I have in the table destination. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Larnu I agree with you when I remove some columns the dataflow task fails, but when I add more columns it doesn't. I guess I'm missing a parameter in my connection string Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=File_Path;Extended Properties="EXCEL 12.0 XML;HDR=YES;IMEX=1" or a parameter in my Excel source Task...

Comment: I don't have a sample handy, but I would ask Excel for the first row and compare the values in that row to your expected header names. Actually, to be lazier, you could just compare the count of columns versus expected and if it's not the same, raise an exception

Comment: @billinkc Thank you for this answer, I thought about it too but I don't want to use the lazy way ;). I actually did the mapping between source an destination and normally SSIS should take into account the source file description and raise an exception if there are more columns in source than destination, and this is what I'm looking for. Otherway I will use your solution. Thanks again for your help.